# Laravel 5, how to make object in correct way?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have the service for **UserController**

```
class UserService
{

  protected $user;

  public function __construct(User $user) {
      $this->user = $user;
  } 

  public function getAll()
  {
     $this->user->get();
     // do something with $this->user
  }

  public function update($data)
  {
      return $this->user->update($data);
  }

}

class UserController extends Controller
{

  private $service;

  public function __construct(UserService $service)
  {
      $this->service = $service; // < ------ error
  }

  public function index(User $user)
  {
      return $this->service->getAll();
  }

  public function update(Request $request, User $user)
  {
      return $this->service->update();
  }

}
```

Needed to avoid the situation when I should make object inside each method of the controller

How can I make object from UserService with parameter $user in the constructor for all methods of the controller?

Comment: You forgot to import the `UserService` with `use namespace/to/UserService;` before the class declaration.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte I specially missed this namespace in this question but in my code, of course, there is

Comment: Please update your question with the real code and with the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Without an error message, it's pretty hard to answer your question. It could be everything from a typo to a complete deadlock in loading your dependences.

That said. You probably didn't add your service to the service container: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/controllers#dependency-injection-and-controllers

Create a [`ServiceProvider`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/providers) for your service like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use YourNameSpace\UserService;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class UserServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register bindings in the container.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton(UserService::class, function ($app) {
            return new UserService($app->user));  // Not sure it's $app->user. But you probably know what to do.
        });
    }
}
```

Then run a `composer dump-autoload` and it should work.

Comment: This is not necessary. The DI container will do that automatically.

Comment: I've never gotten DI to work without explicitely adding providers, but that was "back" in versions 5.1 to 5.4. Might be changed indeed.